# Parsing specific HTML code with Java and jsoup

Tags: java, html, regex, parsing, jsoup

I've been pondering how to implement a logic to parse this block of html code I have. I'm using jsoup, Java and Android at the moment.

Basic structure to display (the one I'm looking for):

22:48 **url1**: Random message

22:44 **url2**: Even more random message!

The code (stored in Element object, which is provided by jsoup):

```
22:48
<strong> <a href="www.randomUrl.com">url1</a>:</strong> Random message.22:44 
<strong> <a href="www.randomUrl.com">url2</a>:</strong> Even more random message!22.42
<strong> <a href="www.randomUrl.com">url3</a>:</strong> This is a dumb message9922.20
<strong> <a href="www.randomUrl.com">url4</a>:</strong> This is a dumb message3
```

How I wish it to be "cleaned up":

```
22:48 <strong> <a href="www.randomUrl.com">url1</a>:</strong> Random message.
22:44 <strong> <a href="www.randomUrl.com">url2</a>:</strong> Even more random message!
22.42 <strong> <a href="www.randomUrl.com">url3</a>:</strong> This is a dumb message99
22.20 <strong> <a href="www.randomUrl.com">url4</a>:</strong> This is a dumb message3
```

Of course I wouldn't mind saving time of a row, the url and the message to some dedicated array lists and then removing the html. But I'm looking forward to hearing how you would deal with this kind of parsing. As the problem is that the random message can be any kind of string, which means it can include a time (22:33). So I can't separate the rows just by using regex based on time.

I'm wondering if the proper approach would be to parse it by using time and the strong-element  simultaneously, as it seems that the strong-element always starts a new row.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

JSoup is a great and valuable library. However, subtile changes on partial text cannot be easily achieved when not clearly delimited by explicit start and end tags.

As all your annoying time stamps seems to be always followed by a <strong> tag, you can remove time on all sequences matching "TIME(eventually followed by whitespaces)<strong>".

This can be done with a quite simple String.replaceAll regex:

```
html = html.replaceAll("(\\d{2}[:\\.]\\d{2})(\\s*<strong>)","$2");
```

Answer (score 0):

String z = s.replaceAll("(\\d{2}[:\\.]\\d{2})\\s*[\n\r]\\s*", "\n$1 ").trim();